# How to make angled text in webpage by using HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the CSS animation for the Menu. Here I want to make the menu as shown in the image. My question is how to write the menu text like in this sample image and make onclick event for each text? The `Onclick` event might use the CSS @Keyframes (For making some animations).

[image: Sample Menu screen]

I am newbie to the web designing field, and it looks very complex for me.

Comment: SVG would be the way to go, or an image with image maps

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS transforms

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(degrees);
transform:rotate(degrees);
```

Use it on the whole outer wrapper, so you wont have to do it individually on all the links.

Comment: That might angle the image but the text is on a curved path. Your answer does not address that issue.

Comment: Okay so maybe add a few additional degrees to each link and offset it from the top by a few pixels. The links aren't curved , they're straight. It appears curved because of the curved background. Notice the baseline of each link.

Comment: Could be...it's hard to tell without knowing exactly what he wants. I agree that rotating the ul/div or whatever would be useful though.

Comment: I already tried this, won't support for responsive design. What i want is If I click the links (Link text are fore in Image) then the entire group need to be zoomed in (rotated zoom) and the clicked text need to be present infront of the user.

Comment: I would suggest you dont use angled divs on smaller screens.